# Method is giving me 2 input next line when I have 1

Tags: java

I'm working on a class that creates a puzzle with arraylists, I'm having problem with FillWords method,
This is a method that asks the user to input words to fill a 2D ArrayList for a puzzle game. When I run the code, this method is giving me double input next line when I only have one input next line?

[![Image1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpoZ9.png

```
import java.util.*;

public class simplePuzzle
{
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Random rd = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        char[][] words;
        int size;

        displayPurpose();
        size = getSize();
        words = new char[size][size];
        fillWords(words,size);
        //displayWords(words,size);
    }//of main

    /**
     * This method displays the main purpose of this program
     */
    private static void displayPurpose()
    {
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("        This program creates a simple word puzzle                        ");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    }//of displayPurpose

    /**
     * This method asks the user for a size input
     * @param size the size of the puzzle
     */
    private static int getSize()
    {
      //asks the user for the size of the puzzle and checks if the input is between 5 and 10, stores the var in an int dataType and returns it to size
      int size;
      System.out.print("What is the size of the puzzle you would like to create (>=5 and <= 10): ");
      size = input.nextInt();
      if (size >= 5 && size <= 10  )
      {
        return size;
      }
      else
      {
        System.out.println("******Invalid size, MUST be ()>= 5 and <= 10)****** ");
        System.out.print("What is the size of the puzzle you would like to create (>=5 and <= 10): ");
        size = input.nextInt();
        return size;
      }
    }//getSize
    /**
     * This method asks the user for puzzle words and stores them in the 2d array list
     */
    private static void fillWords(char[][] words, int size)
    {
      // Asks the user for puzzle words, word cannot exteed the size of the puzzle and the letter of the word starts at random number on the puzzle grid.
        String puzzleWord;
        int wordLength;
        int wordStart;
        System.out.printf("%nEnter %d words, each word should be no more than %d characters long", size, size );
        System.out.println("");
        for(int i= 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            do{
                System.out.println("Please enter a word:" );
                puzzleWord = input.nextLine();
                if (puzzleWord.length() > size){
                    System.out.printf("Word cannot fit in the puzzle. It MUST be <= %d characters in length", size);
                }
            }while(puzzleWord.length() > size);
            for(int k= 0; k < puzzleWord.length(); k++){
                wordLength = puzzleWord.length();
                wordStart = size - wordLength ;
                int v = rd.nextInt(wordStart) + 0;
                //------------------------MAX----MIN
                words[i][k]= puzzleWord.charAt(v);
            }
        }
    }//fillWords

}//end
```

Comment: please format your code  properly

Comment: And make it complete, how is `input` defined and created? Same goes for `rd`.

Comment: what is the value in the size variable

Comment: the code you wrote does not match the output in the image

Comment: i have pasted in the complete code.

Comment: You declared size twice in your code.

Comment: I see but I don't think thats the problem but thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are having problems with the scanner, add

```
input.nextLine();
```

After the line when you read the size. It should look like:

```
int option = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine();
```